# Inverse of the following matrix.

Tags: matrices, inverse

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
       (m+2) &  2\cdot1{^\prime}_m \\\
       2\cdot1_m  &  I_{m}+J_{m,m}\\
        \end{array}\right]
$$

Is there a closed form of  $M^{-1}$?

Where $I_m$ is an identity matrix, $1_m$ is a column vector of ones and $J_{m,m}$ is a matrix of ones.

Comment: You can use the Sherman-Morrison formula to invert $M$ and then read off the trace.

Comment: I need the inverse of M, not trace. Sorry about that.

Comment: @rxk011 in that case Woodbury- / Sherman-Morrison formula is indeed easier. Try to write $M = I_{m+1} + UU^T - VV^T$ for suitable matrices $U,V$.

Comment: @HansEngler, actually in this case there is a simpler way (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\left( {{\bf I}_{\,m}  + {\bf J}_{\,m} } \right)$ has a quite compact inverse, which is easy to demonstrate to be:
$$
\left( {{\bf I}_{\,m}  + {\bf J}_{\,m} } \right)^{\,{\bf  - 1}}  = \left( {{\bf I}_{\,m}  - {1 \over {m + 1}}{\bf J}_{\,m} } \right)
$$
then we can proceed in two alternative ways:

1. use [Blockwise Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), which is
   $$
   \left[ {\matrix{
      {\bf A} & {\bf B}  \cr 
      {\bf C} & {\bf D}  \cr 
    } } \right]^{\,\,{\bf  - 1}}  = \left[ {\matrix{
      {\left( {{\bf A - BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}} \right)^{\,{\bf  - 1}} } & {{\bf  - }\left( {{\bf A - BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}} \right)^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} }  \cr 
      {{\bf  - D}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}\left( {{\bf A - BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}} \right)^{\,{\bf  - 1}} } & {{\bf D}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf  + D}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}\left( {{\bf A - BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf C}} \right)^{\,{\bf  - 1}} {\bf BD}^{\,{\bf  - 1}} }  \cr 
    } } \right]
   $$
2. standing the formula for the inverse of $\left( {{\bf I}_{\,m}  + {\bf J}_{\,m} } \right)$ and the fact
   that $\mathbf M$ is symmetric, we can assume that 
   $$
   {\bf M}_{\,m} ^{\,\,{\bf  - 1}}  = \left[ {\matrix{
      a & {b\overline {\bf 1} _{\,m} }  \cr 
      {b{\bf 1}_{\,m} } & {c{\bf I}_{\,m}  + d{\bf J}_{\,m} }  \cr 
    } } \right]
   $$
   then, imposing that
   $$
   \eqalign{
     & {\bf I}_{\,m}  = {\bf M}_{\,m} {\bf M}_{\,m} ^{\,\,{\bf  - 1}}  =   \cr 
     &  = \left[ {\matrix{
      {m + 2} & {2\overline {\bf 1} _{\,m} }  \cr 
      {2{\bf 1}_{\,m} } & {{\bf I}_{\,m}  + {\bf J}_{\,m} }  \cr 
    } } \right]\left[ {\matrix{
      a & {b\overline {\bf 1} _{\,m} }  \cr 
      {b{\bf 1}_{\,m} } & {c{\bf I}_{\,m}  + d{\bf J}_{\,m} }  \cr 
    } } \right] =   \cr 
     &  = \left[ {\matrix{
      {\left( {m + 2} \right)a + 2mb} & {\left( {\left( {m + 2} \right)b + 2c + 2md} \right)\overline {\bf 1} _{\,m} }  \cr 
      {\left( {2a + \left( {m + 1} \right)b} \right){\bf 1}_{\,m} } & {c\,{\bf I}_{\,m}  + \left( {2b + \left( {m + 1} \right)d + c} \right){\bf J}_{\,m} }  \cr 
    } } \right] \cr} 
   $$
   we arrive at:
   $$
   \left\{ \matrix{
     \left( {m + 2} \right)a + 2mb = 1 \hfill \cr 
     \left( {m + 2} \right)b + 2c + 2md = 0 \hfill \cr 
     2a + \left( {m + 1} \right)b = 0 \hfill \cr 
     c = 1 \hfill \cr 
     2b + c + \left( {m + 1} \right)d = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
     a = \left( {m + 1} \right)/\left( {m^{\,2}  - m + 2} \right) \hfill \cr 
     b =  - 2/\left( {m^{\,2}  - m + 2} \right) \hfill \cr 
     c = 1 \hfill \cr 
     d = \left( {2 - m} \right)/\left( {m^{\,2}  - m + 2} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
   $$